# jQuery undefined in content page when using master pages which has jQuery reference

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages

I have a nested master page. A parent master page, a child master page and a content page whose master page is the child master page. I have a reference to jQuery in the parent master page in the head section.`<script type="text/javascript" src='<%#ResolveUrl("~/includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>' ></script>` & Page.Header.DataBind(); in the OnLoad event.

I am using jQuery in all the pages including the master pages. However I am getting "Error: $().ready is not a function" in the content page. If I include jQuery reference in the content page it works.

Question: If the reference to jQuery is in the master page head section, why aren't the content pages able to use jQuery? When I do view source, the script tag with jQuery is there and it works.

The master pages and content page are merged during rendering and sent to the browser as a single html page so I am not sure when master pages are used, jQuery references break.

**UPDATE:**

When I changed '$.ready(function()' to 'jQuery(document).ready(function($)' it worked! I am not loading any other javascript libraries and I am not using MS Ajax.

Comment: Can you post the rendered head of the master (when it doesn't work)?

Comment: You said it works if you include it in the contentpage? Include jQuery both in the masterpage and the contentpage and compare the generated HTML to see the difference.

Comment: If you include it in the master and content pages, then you could be downloading the script twice.  Performance wise, you don't want to do that.  Sounds like you have a compatibility issue -- what happens when you replace $.() with jQuery.()?  Do you still get the error?  Are you including any other JavaScript libraries -- that could be the culprit.

Comment: @Peter: If the reference is in the content page, it looks like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> which is somehwere in the html body. jQuery works. If I put it in head section, jQuery doesn't work in the content page. Not sure why if in both cases it's the same html file.

Comment: @Nick: <script type="text/javascript" src='/rootfoldername/includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>. When I click on this in html source, the jquery file displays but jQuery in content page doesn't work.

Comment: @D: I wanted to have the reference only in the parent master page without duplicating anywhere else but it didn't work. See my new update. The non aliased call worked but I am not sure why it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, and I didn't notice this before, but is your original call to `$.ready(function() {})`, which didn't work, but `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})` did work?  Does your call work if you use `$(document).ready(function () {} )`?  Just wanted to make sure it's not a typo.  The jQuery docs say the `$.ready(function() {})` is valid, but it's not recommended.

OK, assuming it's not a typo, it definitely sounds like you have a conflict with the '$' variable.  If you're using third-party controls or ASP.NET AJAX, you may run into conflicts (even though you may not be including the JS file explicitly).

If you could post what gets output by the browser after your page loads, that would help.

Also, if you run Fiddler (or some other traffic request tool), you can see if any JS references are being downloaded.  Look not only for .JS files, but also .AXD files (some third-party tools name these files ScriptResource.axd or WebResource.axd, and they may redefine the '$' variable).

You may want to check out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) on the jQuery API page about the noConflict function.  This helps when you have a conflict with the $ variable.

Without seeing the output, it's tough to diagnose.  But hopefully this helps.

Comment: "$(document).ready(function($) {..." works only when I have a reference to jQuery in the content page. Otherwise it's 'Error: $(document).ready is not a function' (in FireFox) even though I have jQuery reference in the parent master page. It's not a typo. When I add 'jQuery.noConflict();' in the root masterpage, the error becomes 'Error: $ is not a function'. The axd references i see belong to the ASp.NET runtime. I am not using any third party libraries unless the MS web extensions are messing something up and conflicting with jQuery when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

i also have the same issue, it sounds like a jQuery conflict
i fixed my issue :

```
     <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.noConflict();
           
         });
</script>
```

in the `<head>` section